# Use Mongoose Schema in Multiple Files (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have two files I would like to use my Permissions schema in. But I'm getting a Cannot overwrite "example" model once compiled error.

Question: How do I use my Permissions schema in both of my js routes files?

Here's my problem (example):

Permissions Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AccessSchema = new Schema({
  listId: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: Boolean, requried: true},
  completed: {type: Boolean, required: true},
});
const accessSchema = mongoose.model("access", AccessSchema);

const UserPermissionsSchema = new Schema({
  uID: { type: String, required: true },
  access: [AccessSchema],
});
const userPermissionsSchema = mongoose.model("permissions", UserPermissionsSchema);

module.exports = { //Am I exporting wrong?
  Access: accessSchema,
  Permissions: userPermissionsSchema,
};
```

File1 - Users Routes:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const { Permissions } = require("../models/permissions"); //first use

router.post("/users", (req, res) => {
  Permissions.findOne({},{}).then(() => {})
  Users.findOne({},{}).then(() => {})
});


module.exports = router;
```

File2 - Items Routes:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const {Permissions} = require("../models/permissions"); //second use

router.post("/users", (req, res) => {
  Permissions.findOne({}, {}).then(() => {})
});

module.exports = router;
```

Am I Requiring and/or exporting things wrong? Is using a schema in multiple files possible?

Comment: The code seems correct. Your error was confusing.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason just requiring mongoose fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I overlooked it all day because it makes no sense why it fixes it...

Anyways, the solution is to add:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

- to all of the files that are using the Schema. Again I have no idea why this fixes it, but it did.